# Implementing the relative prime(m,n) function

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to obtain the following answer using Python.

> Enter your name: dog
>
> Enter 4 numbers separated by commas, Cat, Lion, or Eulerphi:1,1,1,2.
>
> The distance between (1,1) and (1,2) is 1.0.
>
> Enter 4 numbers separated by commas, Cat, Lion, or Eulerphi: Eulerphi
>
> Enter a number: 4
>
> 1 is an Euler Phi for 4
>
> 3 is an Euler Phi 4
>
> Enter 4 numbers separated by commas, Cat, Lion, or Eulerphi: Lion
>
> Perhaps you want to sing 13 Bryan Mark songs
>
> Enter 4 numbers separated by commas, Cat, Lion, or Eulerphi: Cat
>
> You are on loop iteration 4
>
> Enter 4 numbers separated by commas, Cat, Lion, or EulerPhi: 0,0,0,10
>
> The distance between (1,1) and (1,2) is 10.0
>
> Thank you dog. The smallest distance between points was 1.0

The only problem is when i type EulerPhi, Python doesn't print out

> 1 is an Euler Phi for 4
>
> 3 is an Euler Phi for 4
>
> Thank you dog, The smallest distance between points was 1.0

I do not know what to write to print out. Profs said use GCD method

using `def relativeprime(m,n)`. could anyone help me out with printing out the aforementioned answer? I need major help with coding EulerPhi and printing out "Thank you Dog. The Smallest distance between points was 1.0"

Here are the following the code i have implemented.

```
from math import sqrt.

from random import randint

def main():

    name=input("Enter your name")

    loopindex=1

    distance=0

    smallestdistance=10000000000000000

    while distance <=10:
        kim=input("Enter 4 numbers separated by commas, Cat, Lion, or EulerPhi:")
        if kim=="Cat":
            print("you are on loop iteration",loopindex)
        elif kim=="Lion":
            print("Perhaps you want to sing", randint(1,100),"Bryan Mark songs")

        elif kim=="EulerPhi":
            number=eval(input("Enter a number: "))
            def relativePrime(m,n):
                m=1
                n=0
                n,m= m,n%m
                for i in range(i,number):
                    if relativeprime(i,number):
                        print(i, "is an EulerPhi for,", str(number))

        else:
            n1,n2,n3,n4=eval(kim)
            d=sqrt((n1-n3)**2+(n2-n4)**2)
            print("The distance between (",n1,",",n3,") and (",n2,",",n4,") is",d)
            if d< smallestdistance:
                    smallestdistance=d
                    print("Thank you",name,".","The smallest distance between points was",d)
        loopindex=loopindex+1
main()
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: He is asking why his EulerPhi section is not printing the answer out.

Comment: You could improve this question by limiting it to the part you have a question about.  For example, cut out the sections about all the different animals and so on.

Comment: Thank you Marsh. yes thats my question.  and I wanted to show all of my work so that one of y'all who are professionals on this field could help me out. I am not merely asking for answers; I'd like to learn and find my mistake so i can learn. thank you in advance

Comment: @Chris then please **edit the question**. Read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You are only defining a function called relativePrime. You never call it anywhere that I can see.